# Set of 6 equations with 6 unknowns

Tags: elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations

Find all real solutions of 
 $\begin{cases}x=-t-z\\y=tz\\t=-u-q\\z=uq \\u=-x-y\\q=xy\end{cases}$ 
 
By multiplying all the sides of all the equations respectively we get that either one of the unknowns is equal to zero or that $xtu=1$. Nevertheless, I don’t know how to find solutions for any of these cases. Other methods I’ve tried lead me to expressions with an unknown raised to the 3rd power.

 Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show us what you actually tried. You've tagged the question as number theory. Does that mean you want integer solutions?

Comment: I’ve tried as I wrote below. Not only integer solutions may be correct.

Comment: Use of symmetry would simplify the system.

Answer (score 1):

Using elimination,  $q$ satisfies $q(q+2)(q^6-2q^5+4q^4-10q^3+16q^2-12q+4)=0$. The solution $q=0$ does not lead to any solutions. When $q=-2$ then $t=1, u=1, x=1, y=-2, z=-2$ is the only solution.

Comment: Wolfram says the sextic has a real root near $1$.

Comment: @i.m.soloveichik Could you please demonstrate the elimination?